# Failed to Export Default and Another Function

Tags: reactjs

Plan - To render `<List />` element in `index.js`. Displays the todo items the user has created.

Error -

```
./src/components/App.jsx
Attempted import error: './List' does not contain a default export (imported as 'List').
```

index.js -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {List, Render} from './components/List';
import App from './components/App';
import '../src/styles.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Render />
  , document.getElementById("list"));
```

List.jsx -

```
import react, { useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var todoItems = [];
const inputRef = useRef();

function onClick() {
    todoItems.push(inputRef.current.value);
    console.log("Pushed item in the array!");
    render(inputRef.current.value);
}

function Render(value) {
    todoItems.forEach(function a(item) {
        <h1>{item}</h1>
    });
}

function List() {

    return (
        <div className="mainbox">
            <div className="inputdiv">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref={inputRef}
                  placeholder="Enter Task..."
                  className="textbox"
                  id="taskName"
                />
                <button className="button" onClick={onClick}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export {List, Render};
```

I also tried -

```
export default List;
export {Render};
```

But it says useRef() cannot be called at the top level.
So I moved the `inputRef` to the `List()`, but it says that `Render` isn't defined.

Thanks!

P.S

After this import/export problem is solved, will the `<h1>` display?

```
function Render(value) {
    todoItems.forEach(function a(item) {
        <h1>{item}</h1>
    });
}
```

**EDIT** -

index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link font-family: "Montserrat" , sans-serif;
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren|Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/styles.css">
  <title>Mandy's Todo-List App!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="list">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to use two `ReactDOM.render()`s. And you do not need to manipulate `index.html` either.

Comment: Everything wrapped inside `App` component will eventually get rendered inside `<div id='root'>`. Render your `todoItems` inside `List` component if you will, and then import `List` component inside `App` component.

Comment: @Hamidreza Thanks but I'm getting this error - `Target container is not a DOM element.` after `import List, {Render} from './List';
 function App() {
 ReactDOM.render(
<Render />
 , document.getElementById("list"));`

Comment: Delete the second `ReactDOM.render()` from `index.js` and `<div id='list'>` from `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  function addTodo() {
    setList([...list, value]);
  }

  useEffect(() => setValue(''), [list]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
      <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
      {list.map((item, index) => <h1 key={index}>{item}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```